# How can I determine what is causing the used disk space to slowly increase in Linux?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, disk-usage

I have just done a fresh install of Raspian Buster Lite on a Raspberry Pi 3B, and installed [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/) along with [Node Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) to just scrape a few simple diagnostics - particularly the available disk space.

The problem is that the available disk space appears to be continuously decreasing. I can check the bytes availble by using `df -B1`, which returns the following (13.08 GB from the "16 GB" SD card used):

```
pi@raspberrypi:/home $ df -B1

Filesystem       1B-blocks       Used   Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      15383740416 1647845376 13078351872  12% /
devtmpfs         480808960          0   480808960   0% /dev
tmpfs            485527552          0   485527552   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            485527552    6459392   479068160   2% /run
tmpfs              5242880       4096     5238784   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            485527552          0   485527552   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   264289280   54748672   209540608  21% /boot
tmpfs             97103872          0    97103872   0% /run/user/1000
```

If I examine this periodically, it just reduces. Checking it a few minutes later shows the following:

```
Filesystem       1B-blocks       Used   Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      15383740416 1648463872 13077733376  12% /
devtmpfs         480808960          0   480808960   0% /dev
tmpfs            485527552          0   485527552   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            485527552    6459392   479068160   2% /run
tmpfs              5242880       4096     5238784   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            485527552          0   485527552   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   264289280   54748672   209540608  21% /boot
tmpfs             97103872          0    97103872   0% /run/user/1000
```

I can examine this metric in the Prometheus database using [Grafana](https://grafana.com/):

[image]

It may well just be some logs or something, but I want to understand it a little better. Based on this graph, it seems the space is reducing at a rate of around 2.9 MB per hour, which seems like a lot to me.

Ideally I suppose I am looking for a way to view only files that have changed in size, let's say in the last minute or something. What would be a good way to track down the source of this? Thanks for your patience - I am brand new with linux.

---

### Edit

In case anyone is interested, I discovered that almost all of the 2.9 MB/hour can be attributed to the write ahead logs (WAL) in Prometheus - you can read about how it stores data [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/). I was able to observe the WAL directory building up by using the command

`watch -d "sudo du -s -B1 /home/pi/prometheus/data/*"`

which highlights nicely the changing files:

[image]

As Richie Frame hinted at, every so often (I believe it is supposed to be every 2 hours in Prometheus by default, but I need to check that) the data is compacted from the WAL and is put into more permenant storage, which is more efficient in terms of required disk space. You can see on Grafana the compaction happening (this was taken overnight whilst the Pi was otherwise just sitting there idle), and some of the disk space being released:

[image]

I am not sure why the disk space seems to jump by a large amount only every 4 hours, instead of the expected 2 hours, but that is a task for another day. Thanks for everyone for your help!

Comment: To check what logs are written, you could do something like `watch -d "ls -lt /var/log/**/* | head"`. Changes will be highlighted.

Comment: 3MB per hour actually seems very reasonable, at some point prometheus will archive and compact the data, and it will be much smaller

Comment: @RichieFrame I can now see the compaction happening - I have added an edit to the post in case you are curious. Thanks!

Comment: compaction time varies based on several factors, if the files are small it will wait longer (i think this is what it said when i read the docs a while ago)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be this command:

```
watch -d "ls -lt /var/log/**/* | head"
```

`watch` runs the following command by default every 2 seconds. The `-d` flag highlights differences after each execution.

`ls -lt` lists files according to their last modified date (newest ones first), `**/*` is a glob to find all files recursively.

Lastly, `head` is used to output only the first 10 lines.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the recently updated files on your system using something like

```
find / -type f -newermt '-5 minutes'`
```

You can combine that with a size display:

```
find / -type f -newermt '-5 minutes' -exec stat -c '%10s %n' {} + `
```

Comment: better `/proc` to be excluded

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer. I accepted Panki's answer, only simply because it was the first one I tried and it did the trick! Thank you for your contrbution.

Answer (score 1):

as root do `crontab -e`
and do something like

```
30 * * * * *   /root/checkmydiskspace.sh
```

that will run the bash script `/root/checkmydiskspace.sh`, every half hour, which you have to create.  Look up crontab and decide if you need to check more often.

That script would be this, and would output necessarily info to help you pinpoint **where** the disk space is getting used up over time.

```
#!/bin/bash

now=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M')

filename=wheremydiskspacegone_$now.log

du -sh /* > /root/$filename
```

Also, `chmod 744 /root/checkmydiskspace.sh`

look at the created log files, find out where stuff is happening, then alter `du -sh /*` to be `du -sh /usr/*` for example; work your way into the sub folders where the `du` is showing most space used.

Of course you could just do `du -sh /*` up front and see which folder has the most stuff and that is likely the culprit.  But with all the log files, every X minutes or whatever, you have everything needed to deduce what is specifically happening and where.  Then it would be a matter of determining which program or process is causing that.

Comment: This will create more log files and use up space - so a bit counter-productive here imo